# Python: Synchronous URL calls inside an Async Block

Tags: python, python-asyncio

### Background

I have a list of 3000 objects that I want to delete from a web application, each object has 10 child objects that need to be deleted first, Unfortunately each of these needs to be synchronous as they need to be done in a specific order.

I have the following;

```
async def resource_delete(jobid, headers):
      try:
        async with client.get(content_url) as resp:
            print(jobid)
            data = await resp.read()
            output = json.loads(data)
            try:
                output = output['resources']

                for resource in output:
                    if resource['type'] == 'blah1':
                        id1 = resource['identifier']
                    if resource['type'] == 'blah2':
                        id2 = resource['identifier']
                    if resource['type'] == 'blah3':
                        id3 = resource['identifier']
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError("No Output resources for Job {}".format(jobid))

            for entry in ['f2', 'f3', 'f1']:
                url = "{baseurl}//{entry}".format(baseurl=BASEURL, id=jobid, entry=entry)
                try:
                    async with client.get(url) as resp:
                        output = await resp.text()
                        if resp.status != 200:
                            print("Failed to Delete Entry file", entry, output)
                except ValueError:
                    print(emsg)

            design_url = "{baseurl}/{id}".format(baseurl=BASEURL, id=)
            spec_url = "{baseurl}//{id}".format(baseurl=BASEURL, id=)
            cabinet_url = "{baseurl}/{id}".format(baseurl=BASEURL, id=)
            # print("Delete")
            try:
                async with client.delete(url) as resp:
                    output = await resp.text()
                    if resp.status != 200:
                        print("Failed Deletion", id1, "jobid: ", jobid, output)
            except ValueError:
                print(emsg)
            # print("Delete")
            try:
                async with client.delete(url) as resp:
                    output = await resp.text()
                    if resp.status != 200:
                        print("Failed Deletion", id2, "jobid: ", jobid, output)
            except ValueError: 
                print(emsg)
            # print("Delete cabinet")
            try:
                async with client.delete(url) as resp:
                    output = await resp.text()
                    if resp.status != 200:
                        print("Failed Deletion", id3, "jobid: ", jobid, output)
            except ValueError:
                print(emsg)

    except ValueError:
        print(emsg)
    
    jobs_url = "url/{id}".format(baseurl=BASEURL, id=jobid)

    try:
        async with client.delete(jobs_url) as resp:
            output = await resp.text()
            if resp.status != 200:
                print(jobid, output)
    except ValueError:
        pass

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers, read_timeout=None, connector=connector) as client:
        await tqdm.gather(*[
            asyncio.ensure_future(resource_delete(client, id))
            for id in jobids
        ], total=count)
```

*urls removed for security

However, I can't get this to work.

I've also tried making the calls synchronous (using requests library) and made the task asynchronous, but that doesn't complete the task.

`await tqdm.gather(*[asyncio.ensure_future(resource_delete(jobid, headers))for jobid in next_batch], total=count)`

Really, I just want a way of Asynchronously running 3000 deletes, where each object deletion has to have synchronous calls to delete child objects in order. How can I achieve that? Maybe I have totally the wrong idea?

Comment: How many of these 3000 deletions can run in parallel?

Comment: Probably around 25 at a time